# Git Push resulting in Repository not found

Tags: git, github, git-push

I cloned a repo onto my local drive, made some changes to a file, and did git add + git commit for those changes. When I go to push it, I get these errors

```
git push origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/*******/*****.git/' not found
```

I'm new to Git so I'm not too sure what's going on here. I have access to the repo so it shouldn't be a privacy problem. I am able to make changes to other repos and push them no problem so I have my Git set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below process:

1. git clone repo_name
2. cd repo_name
3. do some changes in the files
4. git add ./
5. check status as git status
6. git commit -m "commit message"
7. git push

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. I forgot to fork over from the original repo. I was trying to push my changes to the original repo which obviously doesn't work